# Can't get absolute path to file C#

Tags: c#, file

[image]

I have very simple program. Here I set the absolute path,but C# thinks that it's a relative path and try to load the file from project directory: `C:\Users\Gleb Kozyukevich\source\repos\ChangeDir\ChageDir\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\C:\test\test.txt`

The path really exists.

What did I miss? I can't get understand

Comment: Change your string using a string verbatim @"C:\test\est.txt"

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild. That code, as far as I can tell, cannot give that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you try.

1. Give file path like

```
string sourceFilePath  = @"C:\test\test.txt";
```

2. Use System.IO.Path.Combine

```
string sourceFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(new []{"C:","test","test.txt"});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is very strange. I've reproduced the code the way I think you wrote it and the result is just fine.

Here the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadAllLines
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: How is you solution differ from what I have suggested ?

Comment: Just trying to help here. Are you offended in some way?

Comment: Nothing to offend about. Just trying to understand how your solution differ apart from it is full program but main thing is common.